Custom wrapper around VS Code Remote-SSH extension
I really appreciate what the remote-ssh extension does: I want to be able to use VS Code to edit code and run commands on remote servers. The existing extension uses your SSH config to figure out what machines you might want to connect to and how to do so.
However I have a cluster of servers with rotating IPs and credentials. They're typically accessed by name or ID e.g. head-node or machine-306. I have a script I use to figure out the IP of  and retrieve the right credentials. I want to be able to go into VS Code and simply type something like ctrl+shift+P cluster-remote and be prompted for a machine name to pass to my script, using the outputs to remote into the machine.
So I can see how to do start doing this with a custom VS Code extension, which I'm prepared to build. But that extension would need to talk to the existing remote-ssh extension - that's the part I don't know how to do. How might I go about doing this? Is there a better way?
